# How to use IMultiValueConverter with MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My viewmodel has these two properties:

```
public ValueType ValueType { get { return _valuetype; } set { _valuetype = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
public double? Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
```

`ValueType` is an `enum`:

```
public enum ValueType
{
    Currency,
    Quotas
}
```

I want to format a textbox using a `IMultiValueConverter` that formats my `Value` property based on my `ValueType` property. If `ValueType` is set to `ValueType.Currency`, I need to display thousand separators and 2 decimal places, or `.ToString("N2")`; if `ValueType` is set to `ValueType.Quotas`, I need to show 8 decimal places and thousand separators, or `.ToString("N8")`. This is my textbox:

```
<TextBox Width="250" TextAlignment="Right"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CurrencyQuotaConverter}">
            <Binding Path="ValueType" Mode="OneWay"/> <!--from my DataContext-->
            <Binding Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay"/> <!--from my DataContext-->
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And this is my converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    ValueType _valuetype = (ValueType)values[0];
    if (values[1] == null) return null; //My Value property is nullable
    double _value = double.Parse(values[1].ToString());
    return _valuetype == ValueType.Currency ? _value.ToString("N2") : _value.ToString("N8");
}

public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    object[] returnedvalue = { null, null };
    returnedvalue[1] = value; //Only my second bound value is twoway mode.
    return returnedvalue;
}
```

You can see that my `ConvertBack()` method is *probably* wrong. My `ValueType` property is bound to two radiobuttons. Changing its value updates the conversion just fine. if I click on the "Currency" RadioButton, my textbox will format my number with 2 decimal places, otherwise, it will show 8 decimal places as intended. But the problem is, the `ConvertBack()` method never updates my `Value` property on my viewmodel, the `set` constructor is never called. And changing my textbox value won't trigger my converter either.

My question is: how do I keep my view correctly formatted and my viewmodel always updated using IMultiValueConverter? Is it even possible? Should I find another solution?

Comment: It might be simpler to add a FormattedValue property to the view model.

Comment: Change mode to `TwoWay`.

Comment: @Clemens and then bind the FormattedValue property to my textbox? How would I keep the Value property updated?

Comment: @aepot my second binding is alreay twoway mode. You mean the multibinding?

Comment: In the setter of the FormattedText property you would parse the string according to the ValueType, and set the Value accordingly.

Comment: In the ConvertBack method you don't have access to the current ValueType, so that approach won't work.

Comment: You may alo use a `DataTrigger` that triggers on `ValueType` and set proper `Text` binding with desired `StringFormat`.

Comment: @KelvinGuedes: For this to work, the `ConvertBack` method has to return an `object[]` that contains a `ValueType` and a `double` or whatever the types of your source properties are.